# R: Replicate Vector of Sample Instead of Just a Sample

Tags: r, replication

I want to use `R` to do what I do to sample size of `10` to do the same to set of samples

**What I have**
I got the below `R` code of replicating a Shapiro test for normality [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60681209/normality-tests-repeating-1000-times-in-r-shapiro-wilk-jarque-bera-lilliefors)

```
sim = replicate(1000,shapiro.test(rnorm(10)))
## rejections go like, assuming an alpha of 0.05 :
table(sim["p.value",] < 0.05)
```

Result of rejections go like, assuming an alpha of 0.05 :

| FALSE | TRUE |
| --- | --- |
| 948 | 52 |

**What I want**

Instead of carrying the count test on just a sample size of `10` I want it carried out on a vector of samples say (10, 20,50, 100) with a result with something like this:

| . | FALSE | TRUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 948 | 52 |
| 20 | 970 | 30 |
| 50 | 956 | 44 |
| 100 | 944 | 36 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop - `sapply` and pass those values in `rnorm`

```
out <- t(sapply(c(10, 20, 50, 100), function(x) 
    table(replicate(1000, shapiro.test(rnorm(x)))["p.value",] < 0.05)))
row.names(out) <- c(10, 20, 50, 100)
```

-output

```
out
    FALSE TRUE
10    953   47
20    942   58
50    960   40
100   951   49
```