# R: Do to Bonett Test What Was Done on Shapiro Test

Tags: r

I want to use `R` to do what I do to sample size of `10` to do the same to set of samples

**What I have**
I got the below `R` code of replicating a Shapiro test for normality [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68042013/r-replicate-vector-of-sample-instead-of-just-a-sample)

```
out <- t(sapply(c(10, 20, 50, 100), function(x) 
    table(replicate(1000, shapiro.test(rnorm(x)))["p.value",] < 0.05)))
row.names(out) <- c(10, 20, 50, 100)
```

Result of rejections go like, assuming an alpha of 0.05 :

| . | FALSE | TRUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 953 | 47 |
| 20 | 942 | 58 |
| 50 | 960 | 40 |
| 100 | 951 | 49 |

**What I want**

Instead of carrying out the `Shapiro normality test`, I want to do the `Bonett Test`  on  a vector of samples say (10, 20,50, 100) with a result with something like this:

| . | FALSE | TRUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 998 | 2 |
| 20 | 970 | 30 |
| 50 | 956 | 44 |
| 100 | 944 | 36 |

**What I Traid**

```
library(moments)
out <- t(sapply(c(10, 20, 50, 100), function(x) 
  table(replicate(1000, bonett.test(rnorm(x)))["p.value",] != sqrt(2/pi))))
row.names(out) <- c(10, 20, 50, 100)
out
```

I got this error message

> Error: unexpected symbol in:
> "  row.names(out) <- c(10, 20, 50, 100)
> out"

Comment: Yes to your two (2) questions above.

Comment: Your edit shows that none of them is equal to sqrt(2/pi), thus we have all FALSE values as 0.  In `table`, you don't get that output, so I changed to `factor`, see the output below

Comment: Please note that `==` or `!=` would work better on integer.  Here, the output is a float and you need precision or round

Comment: I updated by `round`ing the output.  Now, it is more realistic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use the same procedure as in `shapiro.test`.  Note that the `==` or `!=` may not work with numeric/float as there is precision involved.  Thus, none of them matched, leaving only TRUE values in the OP's code.  We could convert the logical to `factor` with `levels` specified so that it would always work even if one of them have 0 count

```
out <- t(sapply(c(10, 20, 50, 100), function(x) 
    table(factor(replicate(1000, bonett.test(rnorm(x)))["p.value",] 
           != sqrt(2/pi), levels = c(TRUE, FALSE)))))
row.names(out) <- c(10, 20, 50, 100)
```

-output

```
out
    TRUE FALSE
10  1000     0
20  1000     0
50  1000     0
100 1000     0
```

---

As mentioned above, an option would be to compare on a `round`ed output

```
out <- t(sapply(c(10, 20, 50, 100), function(x) 
     table(factor(round(unlist(replicate(1000, 
       bonett.test(rnorm(x)))["p.value",]), 2) 
            != round(sqrt(2/pi),  2), levels = c(TRUE, FALSE)))))
row.names(out) <- c(10, 20, 50, 100)
out
    TRUE FALSE
10   993     7
20   989    11
50   989    11
100  993     7
```